# ParallelQuery Batching

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, plinq

How can I collect a `ParallelQuery<T>` into batches of size n in parallel? Something like the [MoreLinq Batch function](https://morelinq.github.io/2.8/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Batch__1.htm), but for `ParallelQuery`:

```
ParallelQuery<T[]> Batch(ParallelQuery<T> values, int batchSize)
```

Ideally, it would be lazy and streaming like other `ParallelQuery` methods.

Comment: There's no actual processing work done on the items.  You're just getting them and yielding them when you've collected a batches worth.  There's no expensive work to parallelize.  Just use a normal serial implementation.

Comment: True, it is a cheap operation and could just be serialized. I still think it would be nicer to have it operate on a ParallelQuery since it keeps the parallelism settings intact (eg. WithDegreeOfParallelism, etc.) and it ought to be possible to express.

Comment: The PLINQ library is not extensible, so the batching can't be done in parallel.